# How to use functions from different part of my code in jest testing?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, babeljs, babel-jest

I'm trying to write a test in jest.
I have 2 functions in a different js file that i need to use in order to pass
data to the function im testing.

i tried to use:

1. import {func} from './funcfile' gives:
   SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
2. const {func} = require('./funcfile') gives:
   SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

looking at other topics and google, tried every dependency installation and added configurations to package.json, jest.config.js, .babelrc, babel.config.js.

the only thing that happened is getting an error around type ErrorHandler = ...
where it says a syntax error again excepted ";"

i reverted everything therefore i don't have the files with the changes, willing to try any solution you may seem fit.
[image: the line where the error points to]

[image: require code on jest file]

it crashes on export const phone_number and never event get to the getSubCategory export line....

Edit:

Been asked to add some more code so others could understand better,
Thing is there is not much more code.
I have a file with lots of export const  = ;
(as described in photo)
and eventually the function export const (as described in photo)

on my jest file i just have the import/ require line I added and the test fails there.

the error i get when using the suggested answer :
[image]

Comment: how do you declare `getSubCategoryId` function?

Comment: export const getSubCategoryId = (category) => {....}

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import your utils class and use constants as properties of this exported module, e.g.

```
import * as UTILS from './utils';

...

UTILS.getSubCategoryId('return input')
```

where `utils` is

```
export const getSubCategoryId = (category) => category;
```

Please check example
https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-rujqvm?file=index.ts

Comment: If i import:

import * as UTILS from './utils';

the function is unrecognized

if i import 

import * as DictionaryManagement from './utils/DictionaryManagementUtils';
and then use DictionaryManagement.getSubCategoryById(category);
i get an error

import * as DictionaryManagmentUtils from '../src/utils/DictionaryManagementUtils';
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
(the arrow signs points on the import)

Comment: do you use JS or TypeScript? Which version of JS you use? ES...

Comment: Using JS, not sure about the version, you mean version number or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Combined with VadimB solution had to add these lines to `.babelrc` on root directory

```html
{
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs"]
    }
  }
}
```

Now its all up and working